endcoding of the manufacturer's date in a memeory map of a datasheet
I am looking at the datasheet of a bq2060A battery management chip. It loads some data from an EEPROM connected to it, one of the addresses stores the manufacturer's date in two hexadecimal values. I have failed to figure out the way the date is encoded in these values. The following image shows the relevant line of the memory map. First two columns are the addresses and the last two are the hexadecimal values.

How does 2/25/99 turn into 9817?

Can you post a link to the datasheet that the screenshot is from?

Seconding @MrGerber's request; that doesn't seem to be the TI datasheet, so I'm curious where you got it from. To my knowledge, the BQ2060A is only made by TI.

The datasheet includes an explanation of this format on page 36, which I've reproduced below.

The least significant five bits represent the day of the month from 0 (it's not clear what this would represent; it may be a typo) to 31. The next four bits represent the month, and take a value from 1 to 12. The remaining seven bits are the years after 1980; e.g. 0 means 1980, 10 means 1990, and 44 means 2024.
